# Не показывается JLabel

Tags: java

Решил сделать шахматную доску с цифрами и латинскими буквами. Сделал доску, но лэйбл с цифрами не показываются несмотря на то, что я создал его, а также прописал setText и setVisible. Укажите на мою ошибку.

```
package chess123;    
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.Color;
public class board{
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        for (int j = 1; j<=9; j++) {
        if (j!=9) {
        for (int i = 1; i<=8; i++) {
            JFrame nf = new JFrame();
            nf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            nf.setBounds(i*100, j*100, 100, 100);
            nf.setUndecorated(true);
            nf.setVisible(true);

            if(i % 2 == 0 & j % 2 != 0) {
                nf.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            }
            else if(i % 2 != 0 & j % 2 == 0) {
                nf.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            }
            else if (i % 2 == 0 & j % 2 == 0) {
                nf.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
            else if (i % 2 != 0 & j % 2 != 0) {
                nf.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            }
            if (j == 9) {
                for (int k = 1; k<=8; k++) {
                String l = String.valueOf(k);
                JLabel count = new JLabel();
                count.setText(l);
                count.setVisible(true);
                }       
            }
        }

    }
}
}
}
```

P.S Я знаю что цифры должны быть сбоку, но хочется сначала понять структуру JLabel.

Comment: Не силен в `swing`, но помещать `JLabel` в какой-нибудь фрейм разве не нужно?

Comment: Вот именно это я и не понимаю. Надо чтобы всё разъяснили

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день, вам нужно поместить JLabel на JPanel и не нужно ему указывать setVisible(true), это будет выглядеть примерно так в вашем коде:

```
JLabel count = new JLabel();
count.setText(l);
count.setBounds(x, y, width, height); // задаете координаты по Х, Y, ширину, высоту, либо можно использовать Layout
nf.getContentPane().add(count);
```

Но я бы сделал немного по другому, создал бы свою панель куда бы выводил разметку шахматной доски ну и соответственно JLabel, хотя большой роли это не сыграет, но все же:

```
JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
nf.setContentPanel(contentPanel);

... // Вывод на нее шахматной доски

JLabel count = new JLabel();
count.setText(l);
count.setBounds(x, y, width, height); // задаете координаты по Х, Y, ширину, высоту, либо можно использовать Layout
contentPanel.add(count);
```

Надеюсь, что мой ответ оказался вам полезным, удачи в изучении Swing!

Answer (score 0):

1. Вы инициализируете `JFrame` внутри цикла. То есть каждый раз создаете новую форму и пытаетесь ей задать фон (форме, а не метке). Перенесите код инициализации фрейма за пределы цикла. Потому что форма только одна.
2. Вместо смены цвета фрейма `nf.getContentPane().setBackground(...);` вам нужно каждый раз создавать новый компонент для клеточки и именно ему задавать цвет.
3. Создаваемые метки `JLabel` никуда не добавляются. Вам нужно сразу после создания куда-либо добавлять вашу метку. Например, на панель, которая в свою очередь должна быть на фрейме. Попробуйте использовать панель, имеющую [компоновку `GridLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html).
4. Условие `j == 9` в последнем вложенном цикле никогда не выполнится. Потому что он вложен в ветвление с условием `j != 9`.